# Titanium Empty application exits simulator immediately

Tags: html, ios, titanium, accelerator

I am doing some tests with HTML(5) based (web)Applications for mobile in this I want to check performance of different packages like Titanium and for example Phonegap.

I ran some tests with phonegap which were quite disappointing in terms of performance so now I want to give Titanium a try.

As a webdeveloper a HTML based application is the most logical choice for me and all I really want is to see how the app I have written will run when compiled.

So.. After installing en registering Titanium I choose "HTML-based Application" and wanted to run the iPhone simulator. But the simulator exits without having anything shown.

The log:

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 2.1.4 (11/09/12 12:46 51f2c64)
[INFO] iPhone Device family: universal
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 6.0
[INFO] iPhone simulated device: iphone
[INFO] Performing full rebuild. This will take a little bit. Hold tight...
[INFO] Minimum iOS version: 4.3 Linked iOS Version 6.0
[INFO] Compiling localization files
[INFO] Launching application in Simulator
[INFO] Launched application in Simulator (22.53 seconds)
[INFO] Application has exited from Simulator`
```

Does not really help either, after 22.53 seconds the simulator basically closes.

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought the templates Titanium gives should pretty much run without changing anything..

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I created a new, clean project and also have this problem. 
The same log is shown as above, running a clean project starts the simulator and immediately closes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while and lot's and lot's of frustration. I asked the same question on Titanium's own Q&A board but no response.

In the end what fixed it was deleting the conents of the iPhone Simulator folder in

`/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` deleting the **contents** of this and running the project in the simulator worked for me.

Hope it helps someone!